# I cannot have an E-visa to Vietnam and contemplate not to use an Authorized Visa on Arrival approval letter agency

Tags: thailand, vietnam

As of February 2020 the only state of which I hold a citizenship (Israel) isn't listed in the E-visa eligible states list of the Wikipedia article [Visa policy of Vietnam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Vietnam).

While I cannot have an E-visa to Vietnam, I can use an *Authorized Visa on Arrival agency Approval Letter Agency* (**AVoAALA**), such as the one *formally recommended* in the website of any Vietnam consulate in a certain state.

AVoAALA agencies offer me one year visa approval letter gladly, for a cost that **might** be significantly higher than the one I would likely demanded to pay in a Vietnamese consulate anywhere.

### My problem

I contemplate not to use an AVoAALA but to go to a Vietnamese consulate near to my place of residence and make a passport visa there, but [it is unclear to me from the chart of the Vietnam embassy in Bangkok](https://vietnamembassy-thailand.org/consular-fees-and-charges/), `if I can, and if so`, how much should should it cost, to make a tourist visa *for six months* or *for one year*.

Furthermore, it is unclear to me if further demands besides passport and money are required in general, or for Israeli passport holders in particular.

### My question

What is generally needed (including USD money amount) to make a one year Vietnamese visa, whether single entry or multi entry, in a Vietnamese consulate?